# Haskell. Not seeing laziness despite using list-t's ListT (State s)

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, monad-transformers, state-monad, non-deterministic

I have a scenario of traversing a non-deterministic search space, with an upper bound on the number of visits. Using `ListT (State Int) a`, I have managed to achieve this.

My expectation was that, applying `take 1` on the result would prevent subsequent traversal of the tree once the first solution is reached. This is because `Control.Monad.Trans.State` is said to be lazy, and I am using `list-t` which is "A correct implementation of the list monad-transformer. Useful for basic streaming."

However, this toy program proves me wrong:

```
import qualified Data.List as L
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import qualified ListT as LT
import Debug.Trace

dictionary = ["aabb","aa","bb"]

parse :: String -> [[String]]
parse = take 1 . flip evalState 0 . LT.toList . go [] where
  go ::  [String] -> String -> LT.ListT (State Int) [String]
  go ac "" = trace ("trace: " ++ show ac) (return ac)
  go ac input = do
    callCount <- lift get
    if callCount >= 10 then trace "overflow" mzero else do
      nextWord <- LT.fromFoldable $ filter (`L.isPrefixOf` input) dictionary
      let rest = fromJust $ L.stripPrefix nextWord input
      lift $ modify (+1)
      go (nextWord:ac) rest
```

Output:

```
ghci> parse "aabb"
trace: ["aabb"]
trace: ["bb","aa"]   -- Why this line at all?
[["aabb"]]
```

So, what am I missing, and how can we leverage laziness to exit after the first match?

PS: I don't like the solution of repurposing the state:

```
go ac "" = do
  lift modify (const 10)
  return ac
```

Comment: In real code, don't rely on laziness. Simply control streaming explicitly by using the `ListT` variant of functions, in this case [`LT.take`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-1.0.5.7/docs/ListT.html#v:take).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're missing is here:

```
parse = take 1 . flip evalState 0 . LT.toList . go [] where
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

`toList` is not lazy in the monadic effects. Try `head` instead:

```
parse :: String -> Maybe [String]
parse = flip evalState 0 . LT.head . go [] where
```

More generally, control of how much of the result you consume must be done with `ListT` functions, not `Data.List` functions.

Comment: Thanks. Just noticed that, if I add a line `trace nextWord (pure ())` right after `nextWord <-...`, and run it with `parse "aacc"`, I'm getting "aa" 2 times. I can't see why?! I was expecting 1 time. (piggyback question, sorry)

Comment: @cobra I think that's worth opening another question. It's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Correction: what I said is only true for the `LT.take 1` option (from HTNW's comment to the question). For my purposes `LT.head` is good enough if not better.